# Can light GA aircraft with FDs or couplers use the RVR reduction clause on an ILS?

Tags: faa-regulations, iaps

If you are in a modern GA aircraft, you may have a flight director and/or autopilot that can be coupled to your ILS receiver.  (Certainly, this is true of GA glass...)

Some ILS approaches provide a clause (marked by the * on the minimums and in the notes box on the plate shown below) which allows the RVR minimums to be reduced from 2400 to 1800 if you are using a flight director, HUD, or coupled autopilot to fly the approach to the decision altitude.

[image: KLNK ILS or LOC RWY 18]

**Does this clause apply to light GA aircraft with the appropriate hardware (say a C172 with a G1000 in it), or is it limited to use by transport category/multi-crew operations?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FAA Order 8400.13C](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/8400_13C.pdf) outlines these procedures. Section 7 c outlines the requirements for this procedure. Most of these affect the airport facilities or procedures themselves, and section 5 b outlines the IAP requirements for aircraft:

> Aircraft equipped with an operable FD, or AP with an approach coupler, or HUD which is certified for operation to a minimum of 200 feet HAT are eligible for this operation.

There is also a note under 9 b:

> Single pilot operators are prohibited from using the FD to reduced CAT I landing minimums without accompanying use of an AP with an approach coupler or HUD.

So it would appear that having a FD is not entirely sufficient; a pilot with a FD can use the reduced minimums if they also have one of the following:

- AP with approach coupler
- HUD
- Copilot

Comment: So if I'm reading that right it appears the answer for our hypothetical Cessna 172 with the G1000 and coupled autopilot is "Yes, provided the approach coupling and autopilot are certified for operation to 200 feet height above touchdown, or lower."

Comment: However, section 9(b) of that order requires the "operator" to have OpSpec approval or special authorization (LOA). That's supported [here](http://fsims.faa.gov/WDocs/8900.1/V03%20Tech%20Admin/Chapter%2018/03_018_005.htm): the C052 LOA applies to part 91. But this stuff isn't exactly a model of clarity :-)

Comment: It seems that the APs typically fitted alongside the G1000 *do* support operations down to 200' HAT, so yeah, using the AP to fly the approach would do the trick.

Comment: I'm 90% without diving into regs and manuals that, a coupled autopilot is not what a C172 has, even with a G1000. Coupled is almost always referred to with systems that have 2 AP systems that are coupled and will take over if one fails

Comment: @slookabill You are probably confusing requirements for AutoLand (which DOES require 2 A/P systems engaged) for a coupled approach.  Only one A/P is required, even in the Part 121 airline world, for an approach to be considered "coupled."

Comment: @Pondlife Indeed, it's not clear how one would go about getting LOA C052 issued as a part 91 operator (particularly with the required training bits) - A trip to the FSDO with a cask of your finest drinking stuffs may be required to make it happen.

Comment: Rereading your link @Pondlife -- it looks like C052 is *not* available for normal Part 91 operations...but then again, is it *needed* to begin with?